# Automate a concatenation with arbitrary number of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
#file1 mentions 2 columns while file2 mentions 3
dict2 = ({'file1' : ['colA', 'colB'],'file2' : ['colY','colS','colX'], etc..})
```

I want to do a concatenation of the mentioned columns in a new column for each file.
This should be automated.

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(k, v)) #reads to a df
    df['new'] = df['first_col'].astype(str) + df['second_col'] etc.. #concatenation
```

How can I make this work every time, independent of the number of columns in each dictionary?

Simply to concatenate all the mentioned columns.

**UPDATE**

example:

```
a = {'colA' : [123,124,112,165],'colB' :['alpha','beta','gamma','delta']}
file1 = pd.DataFrame(data = a)
file1

colA   colB
123    alpha
124    beta
112    gamma
165    delta

b = {'colY' : [123,124,112,165],'colS' :['alpha','beta','gamma','delta'], 'colX' :[323,326,378,399] }
file2 = pd.DataFrame(data = b)
file2

colY  colS      colX
123   alpha     323
124   beta      326
112   gamma     378
165   delta     399
```

Comment: Just use `pd.concat(____, axis=1)`?

Comment: Explain what you mean please.

Comment: First off, can you provide some sample data in your post? You need data that corresponds to each of your column labels.

Comment: This isn't possible to post data because each file has different types of data and there are many files. either numeric or strings if it helps.

Comment: You need to create a minimal reproducible and verifiable example of your issue.

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [pandas.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with axis=1, which will

> Combine DataFrame objects horizontally along the x axis by passing in
>   axis=1.

```
import pandas as pd

    a = {'colA' : [123,124,112,165],'colB' :['alpha','beta','gamma','delta']}
    df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data = a)

    b = {'colY' : [123,124,112,165],'colS' :['alpha','beta','gamma','delta'], 'colX' :[323,326,378,399] }
    df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data = b)

df_new = pd.concat((df_1, df_2), axis=1)

print(df_new)
```

**Output:**

```
   colA   colB   colS  colX  colY
0   123  alpha  alpha   323   123
1   124   beta   beta   326   124
2   112  gamma  gamma   378   112
3   165  delta  delta   399   165
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `pd.concat()` with `axis=1`:

```
import pandas as pd

a = {'colA' : [123,124,112,165],'colB' :['alpha','beta','gamma','delta']}
b = {'colY' : [123,124,112,165],'colS' :['alpha','beta','gamma','delta'], 'colX' :[323,326,378,399] }

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i) for i in [a,b]], axis=1)
```

Yields:

```
   colA   colB  colY   colS  colX
0   123  alpha   123  alpha   323
1   124   beta   124   beta   326
2   112  gamma   112  gamma   378
3   165  delta   165  delta   399
```